# HTML5 Canvas render to texture and hiDpi display appears blurry

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, retina-display

I am using the renderToCanvas function from http://kaioa.com/node/103:

```
var renderToCanvas = function (width, height, renderFunction) {
    var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
    buffer.width = width;
    buffer.height = height;
    renderFunction(buffer.getContext('2d'));
    return buffer;
};
```

It works great on standard dpi devices, but when I try to use my renderToCanvas buffers on a hiDpi display, they appear blurry.

For example:

```
m_cachedGraphics = renderToCanvas( width, height, function (ctx)
    {
        ctx.fillStyle="rgba("+0+","+0+","+0+","+(1.0)+")";
        ctx.font="14px Arial";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillText( “Test1”, 100, 100 );
    }
);
```

And below is my draw() function where I also set the hiDpi display:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
if(window.devicePixelRatio == 2)
{
    canvas.setAttribute('width', m_canvasWidth * 2);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', m_canvasHeight * 2);
    ctx.scale(2, 2);
}
ctx.drawImage( m_cachedGraphics, 0, 0 );

ctx.fillStyle="rgba("+0+","+0+","+0+","+(1.0)+")";
ctx.font="14px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
ctx.fillText( “Test2”, 100, 200 );
```

On a hiDpi display, Test1 appears blurry while Test2 appears sharp.

I have tried to modify the renderToCanvas to draw the cached buffer (Test1) in hiDpi resolution but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**

GameAlchemist below had the correct answer. Scaling the image by calling ctx.scale(0.5,0.5) right before the ctx.drawImage call makes "Test1" appear as sharp as "Test2". This only appears to be needed when drawing images though. I added the following helped function:

```
function DrawCachedImage( ctx, cachedImage, pixelRatio, x, y )
{
    ctx.save();
    {
        ctx.scale( pixelRatio, pixelRatio );
        ctx.drawImage( cachedImage, x, y );
    }
    ctx.restore();
}
```

and now instead of calling ctx.drawImage I call:

```
//ctx.drawImage( m_cachedBuildUI, 0, 0  );
DrawCachedImage( ctx, m_cachedBuildUI, 1/window.devicePixelRatio, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: To display properly an image on hiDpi devices, you must have at hand a double width/double height image that you draw at a 0.5/0.5 scale.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. I believe what you are talking about is anti-aliasing. hiDPI devices require everything do be drawn at twice the resolution which is why I am scaling by 2. "Test2" in the code above is drawn correctly.

Comment: So now I think that GameAlchemist is correct. I tried calling ctx.scale(0.5,0.5) right before the ctx.drawImage call and "Test1" appeared as sharp as "Test2".